# PBI Dataset not refreshing after transfer of dataset ownership

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I just used the "Take over" feature to take over the ownership of a pbi dataset from an employee who left the firm. However, since then, I am unable to refresh the dashboard and this is the [image: Error].
It is because there are no credentials currently in the pbi file I think as notified
[image: here].
when I try to put my credentials it does not accept it. Any idea what options should I
[image: pick]

or how I should go about it in general? Thanks

Comment: what other authentication methods do you have other than "Anonymous"?

Comment: @woshishui The options are : Anonymous, basoc, Oauth2 
I have tried entering my power bi credentials for all of them but it says the credentials provided are invalid.

Comment: your power bi credential should have nothing to do with this. assuming this is your company's sharepoint site, you should use Oauth2. If you can't connect, it is likely you don't have permission for the sharepoint site. If that is the case you might need to find the owner of the site and grant you access as a member.